# How to merge two java.util.Properties objects?

Tags: java, properties

I'm trying to have a default `java.util.Properties` object in my class, with the default properties it accepts, and let the developer override some of them by specifying another `java.util.Properties` object, but I couldn't find a nice way for doing that.

The intended usage is the following:

```
Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
defaultProperties.put("key1", "value1");
defaultProperties.put("key2", "value2");

Properties otherProperties = new Properties();
otherProperties.put("key2", "value3");

Properties finalProperties = new Properties(defaultProperties);

//
// I'd expect to have something like:
// 
// finalProperties.merge(otherProperties);
//
```

Comment: Someone answered but removed the answer, stating that the correct way would be using the `putAll()` method, which is the correct answer and achieved what I wanted. I haven't noticed that `java.util.Properties` extends `java.util.Hashtable`.

Comment: Why do you think my answer is not correct?

Comment: It is not technically wrong, but what I wanted was to merge two `java.util.Properties` file without iterating its contents, and it is exactly what the `putAll()` method does.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

`java.util.Properties` implements the `java.util.Map` interface, and so you *can* just treat it as such, and use methods like `putAll` to add the contents of another `Map`.

However, if you treat it like a Map, you need to be very careful with this:

```
new Properties(defaultProperties);
```

This often catches people out, because it *looks* like a copy constructor, but it isn't. If you use that constructor, and then call something like `keySet()` (inherited from its `Hashtable` superclass), you'll get an empty set, because the `Map` methods of `Properties` do not take account of the default `Properties` object that you passed into the constructor. The defaults are only recognised if you use the methods defined in `Properties` itself, such as `getProperty` and `propertyNames`, among others.

So if you need to merge two Properties objects, it is safer to do this:

```
Properties merged = new Properties();
merged.putAll(properties1);
merged.putAll(properties2);
```

This will give you more predictable results, rather than arbitrarily labelling one of them as the "default" property set.

Normally, I would recommend not treating `Properties` as a `Map`, because that was (in my opinion) an implementation mistake from the early days of Java (Properties should have contained a `Hashtable`, not extended it - that was lazy design), but the anemic interface defined in `Properties` itself doesn't give us many options.

Comment: Another danger of seeing Properties as a Map is that it is not "Genericified": `properties.put("key", new Object())` will compile.

Comment: It will compile, yes, and in some cases it will work fine, as long as you get it out again using `get()`, and don't try and retrieve it using `getProperty()`.

Comment: Another valuable information here: with properties, always use `setProperty()` and `getProperty()`. Is it right?

Comment: To be safe, yes, but you can get away with `get()` and `put()` if you're sure you know what you're putting in.

Comment: This helped me much! Just notice that Properties is implemented like a Chain of Responsiblity, but `#get()` and `#put()` were not overriden, so to use the Chain of Responsibility fuctionality (read a value from upper handlers) you have to use `#getProperty()`. IMHO, inheriting `HashMap` without overriding `#get()`/`#set()`(and others) maybe was not the best design decission.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you eventually would like to read the properties from a file, I'd go for loading both files in the same properties object like:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("default.properties"));
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("custom.properties"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You're almost good:

```
Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
defaultProperties.setProperty("key1", "value1");
defaultProperties.setProperty("key2", "value2");

Properties finalProperties = new Properties(defaultProperties);
finalProperties.setProperty("key2", "value3");
```

**EDIT:** replaced `put` by `setProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

putAll():
Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this hashtable. These mappings will replace any mappings that this hashtable had for any of the keys currently in the specified map.

```
Properties merged = new Properties();
merged.putAll(properties1);
merged.putAll(properties2);
```

Line 2 has no effect at all. None of the properties from the first file will be in the merged properties object.

Comment: **Your last line is completely untrue**. All properties in properties1 that are not present in properties2 will by set to the value in properties1 in merged.

Answer (score 1):

Yea you're right just invoke the putAll method and you're done.

Comment: CW to avoid having conflicts even thought this was the answer I was about to give