# How to merge properties defined in multiple beans into single (property) bean?

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have many property sets defined in `spring.xml` created by factory bean. I'm looking for spring solution to merge them into single bean. So:

INPUT: 2 or more beans of type `java.util.Properties`

OUTPUT: single bean of type `java.util.Properties`

Is there something like that in Spring or as free available code? I don't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `java.util.Properties` beans using the `putAll` method.

```
@Resource Properties properties1
@Resource Properties properties2

@Bean
Properties mergedProperties(){
    Properties mergedProperties = new Properties();
    mergedProperties.putAll(properties1);
    mergedProperties.putAll(properties2);
    return mergedProperties;
}
```

See also: [How to merge two java.util.Properties objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004833/how-to-merge-two-java-util-properties-objects)