# how to construct properties list with defaults in java?

Tags: java, properties

this code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
public class P {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties defaultProperties=new Properties();
        defaultProperties.put("a",1);
        System.out.println("default: "+defaultProperties);
        Properties properties=new Properties(defaultProperties);
        System.out.println("other: "+properties);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
default: {a=1}
other: {}
```

using java 8 in eclipse luna.

how should one construct a properties list with defaults?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004833/how-to-merge-two-java-util-properties-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are 2 problems with your code.

1. The default properties don't work when you use `get()` and `put()`.

You instead need to do `setProperty()` and 'getProperty()`.

2. When you print the properties file, it wont include the default properties. The `toString()` method is not so sophesticated.

Use this instead:

```
Properties defaultProperties=new Properties();
defaultProperties.setProperty("a","s");
System.out.println("default: "+defaultProperties);
Properties properties=new Properties(defaultProperties);
System.out.println("other: "+properties.getProperty("a"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `defaultProperties.put()` instead of `defaultProperties.setProperty()`. Therefore, your "a" is not recognized as a property.

So use instead:

```
defaultProperties.setProperty("a", "1");
```

The `properties` object will still be printed empty (that's what the `new Properties(Properties defaults)` constructor [is supposed to do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)!) but if you use:

```
System.out.println(properties.getProperty("a"));
```

You'll see that you get "1".

Comment: you can still use put, because setProperty does simply call put. but there is a distinction between keySet and stringPropertyNames. also the toString method is inherit from HashTable and does only display the properties without default properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use put() method but with a String as value:

```
properties.put("a","1");
```

I know the signature is: `Object java.util.Hashtable.put(Object key, Object value)`

But with

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
    Object oval = super.get(key);
    String sval = (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null;
    return ((sval == null) && (defaults != null)) ? defaults.getProperty(key) : sval;
}
```

If the value is not of type String then this function returns null.

A the end:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("a" , "1");
System.out.println("default: "+properties);
Properties properties2 = new Properties( properties );
System.out.println("other: "+ properties2.getProperty( "a"  ) );
```

Comment: seems like this class is on drugs or something. very strange :(