# Can you source one properties file inside another

Tags: java, properties

I have a file where we store common properties.
Multiple applications are using these when creating beans while every application has their own properties file also. Is there a way to source the common file from the application specific files when working with Java?

I tried sourcing the file and that does not work. Here is what I tried.

common.properties

```
password=abcd
```

application.properties

```
. /etc/application_dir/common.properties
application_log_file=/tmp/app.log
```

I want to read only application.properties in my code and get the properties from common.properties loaded also.
One way is to add common.properties to classpath for the beans also but I want to check if there is a cleaner option like above with only changes in the properties file.

Comment: "sourcing" is a unix shell concept, it doesn't work like that in properties files. Why can you not read from both files individually?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004833/how-to-merge-two-java-util-properties-objects

Comment: I can but I was checking if this is a possibility. Would have made my package simpler.

Comment: @cricket_007 - Not a duplicate, IMO.  The other question is about merging Properties objects, not about doing / expressing that at the file level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no you can't.  But here are some ideas that might help you solve your problem.

1. A Java `Properties` object can be created with another one to supply defaults.
2. You can call `load` or `loadFromXML` multiple times on the same `Properties` object to "overlay" the contents of one properties file over another.
3. Non-XML properties files can have comments introduced by a `#`.  So you could invent a special comment for "sourcing" a property; e.g.

   ```
    #source /etc/application_dir/common.properties
   ```

   and then parse your properties file(s) to pull out the "source" directives before loading the properties files.

   XML properties files can have `<comment>` elements which could be used (abused) in the same way.

---

No ... sorry ... I'm not going to provide code samples.